# Django ImageField core=False in newforms admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the transition to newforms admin I'm having difficulty figuring out how specify core=False for ImageFields.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'core'
```

[Edit] However, by just removing the core argument I get a "This field is required." error in the admin interface on attempted submission. How does one accomplish what core=False is meant to do using newforms admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of "This field is required," you need to make it not required, by using blank=True (and possibly null=True as well, if it's not a CharField).

Answer (score 4):

The `core` attribute isn't used anymore.

From [Brian Rosner's Blog](http://oebfare.com/blog/2008/jul/20/newforms-admin-migration-and-screencast/):

> You can safely just remove any and all `core` arguments. They are no longer used. *newforms-admin* now provides a nice delete checkbox for exisiting instances in inlines.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. I started getting this problems a few revisions ago. Basically, just remove the "core=True" parameter in the ImageField in the models, and then follow the instructions [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to convert to what the newforms admin uses.

Comment: I figured that it had been removed, but I was curious as to how the alternative works. Nothing in that link immediately stands out as a replacement for core=False.